# Retrieving tracking numbers from UPS OAuth API

Tags: rest, oauth, ups

In the old access key based API, you could query by an identifier coming from the customer side, such as the order number:

```
$tracking = new Ups\Tracking($accessKey, $userId, $password);
$shipment = $tracking->trackByReference($order_id);
```

The tracking number would then come back in

```
$shipment->Package->TrackingNumber;
```

It seems like in the new API, UPS TrackService API_oauth2 requires a tracking number.  What if I don't have a tracking number because I'm trying to look it up?  (These packages were shipped by WorldShip, but the people using this don't want to log tracking numbers for every package.)